# What do {readonly} \ {query} mean in UML?

Tags: uml

Are they constraints?

Are they part of standard UML, or are they customized by startUML or EA?

How many of them are there? Where can I find a detailed description of each {xxx} in UML2.5 Specificationformal?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{xxx, yyy, ...}` are properties you can put on attribute/relations/..., *readOnly*

There are predefined list of properties attached to some elements.

`readOnly` is one of the properties of Properties, § 9.5.4 from page 113 of [formal 2017 2.5.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) :

- ‘readOnly’ means that the Property is read only.
- ‘union’ means that the Property is a derived union of its subsets.
- ‘subsets’  means that the Property is a proper subset of the Property identified by
  , where  may be qualified.
- ‘redefines’  means that the Property redefines an inherited Property identified by
  , where  may be qualified.
- ‘ordered’ means that the Property is ordered, i.e., isOrdered = true.
- ‘unordered’ means that the Property is not ordered, i.e., isOrdered = false.
- ‘unique’ means that there are no duplicates in a multi-valued Property, i.e., isUnique = true.
- ‘nonunique’ means that there may be duplicates in a multi-valued Property, i.e., isUnique = false.
- ‘seq’ or ‘sequence’ means that the property represents an ordered bag, i.e., isUnique = false and
  isOrdered = true
- ‘id’ means that the Property is part of the identifier for the class.

`query` is one of the predefined property of Operation Template Parameters,  of [formal 2017 2.5.1](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §9.6.4 page 118 :

- ‘redefines’  means that the Operation redefines an inherited Operation identified by ,
  where  may be qualified.
- ‘query’ means that the Operation does not change the state of the system.
- ‘ordered’ applies when there is a multi-valued return Parameter and means that its values are ordered.
- ‘unordered’ applies when there is a multi-valued return Parameter and means that its values are not
  ordered.
- ‘unique’ applies when there is a multi-valued return Parameter and means that its values have no
  duplicates.
- ‘nonunique’ applies when there is a multi-valued return Parameter and means that its values may have
  duplicates.
- ‘seq’ or ‘sequence’ applies when there is a multi-valued return Parameter and means that its values
  constitute an ordered bag, i.e., isUnique = false and isOrdered = true.

Comment: It should be noted that OMG made properties with the same notation as constraints (that is in curly brackets) bringing maximum confusion (similar to enclosing stereotypes and keywords both in guillemets). See p. 111 of UML 2.5 for a full list of these properties.

Comment: Why {query} is not part of UML, I found an explanation about {query} in 9.6.4 Notation in UML2.5 Specificationformal pdf

Comment: @qwerty_so 
The {readOnly} on page 111 is the constraint, why do you say bringing maximum confusion

Comment: @AndLightLight yes you are right, I edited my answer, is just I didn't see it when I search in formal, it is a huge document, and I did some searches including {} this is why.

Comment: @AndLightLight Because the notation does not make you aware whether it's a property of a constraint. Just see: you _are_ confused. It's even worse since what they call properties in this context are actually more sort of constraints.